# XML writing problem

Tags: c#

I am trying to write to an xml file in a certain structure and am experiencing some issues. I want to write several XElements to a certain XElement in an XML. For ex:

```
        foreach (XMLFieldInfo Field in XMLFields)
            Fields.Add(new XElement("Field", new XElement("Name", Field.FieldID), new XElement("InclusionItems", Field.InclusionListToWriteToXML), new XElement("ExclusionItems", Field.ExclusionListToWriteToXML)));
```

Here i build several XElements i want to add as subnodes to another node in an xml.

```
XElement LockboxConfigTree = new XElement("Student", new XElement("ID", cmbID.Text.Trim()), .................);
```

The ...... is where each element in the list created above will be added but i dont know how many elements there are so i cant find a way to add it to the supernode.

The above is the supernode i want to add the subnodes created above to. The problem is, i cant seem to get the right logic so in the end, the xml will look like this:

```
<Student>
   <ID></ID>
   <Field>
     <Name></Name>
     <InclusionList></InclusionList>
     <ExclusionList></InclusionList>
   </Field>
</Student>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [XElement constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341343.aspx) supports [enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) arguments.

You only have to pass your `Fields` variable:

```
XElement LockboxConfigTree = new XElement("Student",
                                 new XElement("ID", cmbID.Text.Trim()),
                                 Fields);
```

Actually, with LINQ, you don't even need a `Fields` variable:

```
XElement LockboxConfigTree
    = new XElement("Student",
          new XElement("ID", cmbID.Text.Trim()),
          from field in XMLFields
          select new XElement("Field",
                     new XElement("Name", field.FieldID),
                     new XElement("InclusionItems",
                         field.InclusionListToWriteToXML),
                     new XElement("ExclusionItems",
                         field.ExclusionListToWriteToXML)));
```